# Exclude parent categories from the_category() within the loop

Tags: theme-development, categories, loop

I have typical parent and child categories setup as follows:

- Food

  - potatoes
  - corn
  - beats
- Sports

  - soccer
  - football
  - hockey

etc.

In my index.php template I'd like to list the categories of the specific post. The problem is, when I use the_category() it lists the parent categories twice. I'm using the following code:

```
<php echo '<dt>', the_category(', ', 'multiple'), '</dt>', "\n"; ?>
```

And it prints out:

`Food:corn, Food, Food:potatoes`

I believe it is listing the child category "corn" as "Food: corn" followed by the parent category "Food" just as "Food." Is there a way to exclude the parent categories?

The way I'd like it to read is:

`Food:corn, Food:potatoes`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tagged the post in Food, Food:Corn, and Food:potatoes?  Try categorizing it in Food:corn and Food:potatoes only.

Comment: Jonny, that's it. Thanks! If you make your comment an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tagged the post in Food, Food:Corn, and Food:potatoes? Try categorizing it in Food:corn and Food:potatoes only.

I do not believe that there is a means to exclude categories from the_category() function.  You will have to use another function to create a custom query to do so.

[Try some of these](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category#Related).